The kubernetes API server didn't start when using kubeadm to init kubernetes 1.29 cluster in Debian 12
I'm using this command to init a single node Kubernetes cluster (version 1.29.6) in Debian 12 (the Cloud Server config is 2CPU core, 4GB RAM):
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 0.0.0.0 --apiserver-bind-port 6443 --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki --control-plane-endpoint 172.31.227.20 --image-repository registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers --kubernetes-version 1.29.6 --pod-network-cidr 10.11.0.0/16 --service-cidr 10.20.0.0/16 --service-dns-domain cluster.local --upload-certs --v=6

but the apiserver didn't start. This is the output log:
root@k8smaster1:~# kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 0.0.0.0 --apiserver-bind-port 6443 --cert-dir /etc/kubernetes/pki --control-plane-endpoint 172.31.227.20 --image-repository registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers --kubernetes-version 1.29.6 --pod-network-cidr 10.11.0.0/16 --service-cidr 10.20.0.0/16 --service-dns-domain cluster.local --upload-certs --v=6
I0629 13:54:04.277281    1194 initconfiguration.go:122] detected and using CRI socket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
I0629 13:54:04.277505    1194 interface.go:432] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I0629 13:54:04.277524    1194 interface.go:437] Default route transits interface "eth0"
I0629 13:54:04.277615    1194 interface.go:209] Interface eth0 is up
I0629 13:54:04.277670    1194 interface.go:257] Interface "eth0" has 2 addresses :[172.31.227.20/20 fe80::216:3eff:fe08:a823/64].
I0629 13:54:04.277693    1194 interface.go:224] Checking addr  172.31.227.20/20.
I0629 13:54:04.277705    1194 interface.go:231] IP found 172.31.227.20
I0629 13:54:04.277721    1194 interface.go:263] Found valid IPv4 address 172.31.227.20 for interface "eth0".
I0629 13:54:04.277736    1194 interface.go:443] Found active IP 172.31.227.20
I0629 13:54:04.277770    1194 kubelet.go:196] the value of KubeletConfiguration.cgroupDriver is empty; setting it to "systemd"
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.29.6
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
I0629 13:54:04.284869    1194 checks.go:563] validating Kubernetes and kubeadm version
I0629 13:54:04.284898    1194 checks.go:168] validating if the firewall is enabled and active
I0629 13:54:04.298433    1194 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 6443
I0629 13:54:04.298735    1194 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 10259
I0629 13:54:04.298778    1194 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 10257
I0629 13:54:04.298817    1194 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
I0629 13:54:04.298850    1194 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
I0629 13:54:04.298866    1194 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
I0629 13:54:04.298883    1194 checks.go:280] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml
I0629 13:54:04.298900    1194 checks.go:430] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
I0629 13:54:04.298941    1194 checks.go:469] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0629 13:54:04.298965    1194 checks.go:469] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0629 13:54:04.298984    1194 checks.go:104] validating the container runtime
I0629 13:54:04.323387    1194 checks.go:639] validating whether swap is enabled or not
I0629 13:54:04.323519    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable crictl
I0629 13:54:04.323562    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable conntrack
I0629 13:54:04.323597    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable ip
I0629 13:54:04.323622    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable iptables
I0629 13:54:04.323651    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable mount
I0629 13:54:04.323677    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable nsenter
I0629 13:54:04.323701    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable ebtables
I0629 13:54:04.323727    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable ethtool
I0629 13:54:04.323749    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable socat
I0629 13:54:04.323773    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable tc
I0629 13:54:04.323795    1194 checks.go:370] validating the presence of executable touch
I0629 13:54:04.323821    1194 checks.go:516] running all checks
I0629 13:54:04.335097    1194 checks.go:401] checking whether the given node name is valid and reachable using net.LookupHost
I0629 13:54:04.335272    1194 checks.go:605] validating kubelet version
I0629 13:54:04.390631    1194 checks.go:130] validating if the "kubelet" service is enabled and active
I0629 13:54:04.408429    1194 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 10250
I0629 13:54:04.408522    1194 checks.go:329] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
I0629 13:54:04.408573    1194 checks.go:329] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
I0629 13:54:04.408602    1194 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 2379
I0629 13:54:04.408636    1194 checks.go:203] validating availability of port 2380
I0629 13:54:04.408669    1194 checks.go:243] validating the existence and emptiness of directory /var/lib/etcd
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
I0629 13:54:04.408835    1194 checks.go:828] using image pull policy: IfNotPresent
I0629 13:54:04.433813    1194 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-apiserver:v1.29.6
I0629 13:54:04.455505    1194 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-controller-manager:v1.29.6
I0629 13:54:04.480387    1194 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-scheduler:v1.29.6
I0629 13:54:04.504768    1194 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-proxy:v1.29.6
I0629 13:54:04.528110    1194 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/coredns:v1.11.1
W0629 13:54:04.549881    1194 checks.go:835] detected that the sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6" of the container runtime is inconsistent with that used by kubeadm. It is recommended that using "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.9" as the CRI sandbox image.
I0629 13:54:04.571172    1194 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.9
I0629 13:54:04.592957    1194 checks.go:846] image exists: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/etcd:3.5.12-0
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
I0629 13:54:04.593061    1194 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for ca
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
I0629 13:54:05.383472    1194 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for ca certificate
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8smaster1 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.20.0.1 172.31.227.20]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
I0629 13:54:05.821279    1194 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for front-proxy-ca
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
I0629 13:54:06.032112    1194 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for front-proxy-ca certificate
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
I0629 13:54:06.142319    1194 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for etcd-ca
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
I0629 13:54:06.245569    1194 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for etcd/ca certificate
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8smaster1 localhost] and IPs [172.31.227.20 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8smaster1 localhost] and IPs [172.31.227.20 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
I0629 13:54:07.416367    1194 certs.go:78] creating new public/private key files for signing service account users
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
I0629 13:54:07.471046    1194 kubeconfig.go:112] creating kubeconfig file for admin.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
I0629 13:54:07.681919    1194 kubeconfig.go:112] creating kubeconfig file for super-admin.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "super-admin.conf" kubeconfig file
I0629 13:54:08.021273    1194 kubeconfig.go:112] creating kubeconfig file for kubelet.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
I0629 13:54:08.713584    1194 kubeconfig.go:112] creating kubeconfig file for controller-manager.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
I0629 13:54:08.789021    1194 kubeconfig.go:112] creating kubeconfig file for scheduler.conf
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
I0629 13:54:09.059955    1194 local.go:65] [etcd] wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd member to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
I0629 13:54:09.060053    1194 manifests.go:102] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
I0629 13:54:09.060392    1194 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for CA certificate
I0629 13:54:09.060487    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0629 13:54:09.060505    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0629 13:54:09.060520    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0629 13:54:09.060533    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0629 13:54:09.060547    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0629 13:54:09.061412    1194 manifests.go:157] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-apiserver" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.061435    1194 manifests.go:102] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
I0629 13:54:09.061626    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.061643    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.061656    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "flexvolume-dir" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.061672    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.061686    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.061700    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.061715    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0629 13:54:09.062447    1194 manifests.go:157] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-controller-manager" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
I0629 13:54:09.062470    1194 manifests.go:102] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
I0629 13:54:09.062657    1194 manifests.go:128] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-scheduler"
I0629 13:54:09.063157    1194 manifests.go:157] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-scheduler" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
I0629 13:54:09.063180    1194 kubelet.go:68] Stopping the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
I0629 13:54:09.474672    1194 waitcontrolplane.go:83] [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the API server to be healthy
I0629 13:54:09.479055    1194 loader.go:395] Config loaded from file:  /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
I0629 13:54:09.482226    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:09.984459    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:10.483841    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:10.983827    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:11.484677    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:11.984588    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:12.484246    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:12.984096    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:13.483772    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:13.984676    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:14.484591    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:14.984416    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:15.483993    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:15.983874    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:16.484733    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:16.984649    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:17.484512    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:17.984309    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:18.483840    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:18.984732    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:19.484604    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:19.984485    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:20.484374    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:20.984465    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:21.484231    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:21.984095    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:22.483802    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:22.983740    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:23.484616    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:23.984613    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds
I0629 13:54:24.484543    1194 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://172.31.227.20:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds

finally, this failed:
Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'
couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:109
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:259
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:124
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:940
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:1068
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:992
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650
error execution phase wait-control-plane
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:260
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:124
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:940
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:1068
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.7.0/command.go:992
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650

this is the kubelet status:
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-06-29 13:54:09 CST; 7min ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
   Main PID: 1278 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 4288)
     Memory: 33.7M
        CPU: 3.483s
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─1278 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///v>

Jun 29 14:01:43 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: E0629 14:01:43.722129    1278 controller.go:145] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://172.31.227.20:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube->
Jun 29 14:01:43 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: I0629 14:01:43.891811    1278 kubelet_node_status.go:73] "Attempting to register node" node="k8smaster1"
Jun 29 14:01:43 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: E0629 14:01:43.892227    1278 kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://172.31.227.20:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp 172.31.227.2>
Jun 29 14:01:48 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: E0629 14:01:48.313461    1278 event.go:355] "Unable to write event (may retry after sleeping)" err="Post \"https://172.31.227.20:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events\": dial >
Jun 29 14:01:49 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: W0629 14:01:49.741385    1278 reflector.go:539] k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: failed to list *v1.RuntimeClass: Get "https://172.31.227.20:6443/apis/nod>
Jun 29 14:01:49 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: E0629 14:01:49.741461    1278 reflector.go:147] k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:229: Failed to watch *v1.RuntimeClass: failed to list *v1.RuntimeClass: Get "h>
Jun 29 14:01:50 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: E0629 14:01:50.132314    1278 eviction_manager.go:282] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"k8smaster1\" not found"
Jun 29 14:01:50 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: E0629 14:01:50.723613    1278 controller.go:145] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://172.31.227.20:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube->
Jun 29 14:01:50 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: I0629 14:01:50.893410    1278 kubelet_node_status.go:73] "Attempting to register node" node="k8smaster1"
Jun 29 14:01:50 k8smaster1 kubelet[1278]: E0629 14:01:50.893914    1278 kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://172.31.227.20:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp 172.31.227.2>
lines 1-23/23 (END)

Am I missing something? I am using this command and didn't find the apiserver:
root@k8smaster1:~# ps aux|grep apiserver
root        1413  0.0  0.0   6332  2064 pts/0    S+   14:04   0:00 grep apiserver

the troubleshooting command has no output:
root@k8smaster1:~# crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause
root@k8smaster1:~#

this is the kubeadm version:
root@k8smaster1:~# kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"29", GitVersion:"v1.29.6", GitCommit:"062798d53d83265b9e05f14d85198f74362adaca", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2024-06-11T20:22:13Z", GoVersion:"go1.21.11", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

